# i deleted a package(pip), but it still works

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, torch

Because of the problem of torch(2.0.1) module, I want to downgrade torch version.
I deleted torch, install torch version 1.10.2, but still python was working with torch 2.0.1.

So I cleaned pip cache, delete all of pip package(including torch), uninstall python, and re-install python(3.9.7).

now in my computer, module 'torch' isn't installed, but below code is still working.

```
import torch
print(f"Torch Version: {torch.__version__}")
>>> Torch Version: 2.0.1+cpu
```

(vs code)

.
.

```
C:\>pip uninstall torch
WARNING: Skipping torch as it is not installed.
```

(cmd)

what would i do?

Comment: Try this code to get detailes on the real python you run and the location of torch `import torch, sys; print(sys.prefix, torch.__file__)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a classic case of using the wrong Python.

If you run the code with `python main.py`, for example, try `python -m pip uninstall torch`.

This will force your pip uninstall command to use the same pip that you used when running your code.

Bonus: `python -m pip --version` will also tell you exactly which Python it is using and where it's located in your filesystem.